# Creating an error page for a subdomain that doesn't exist

Tags: php, dns, subdomain, errordocument

I've got a number of subdomains on one of my sites.  When someone goes to a subdomain that doesn't exist, I want to redirect to a 404 page on my main domain.

noexist.example.com --> example.com/404.php?subdomain=noexist  (or without the query string if HTTP_REFERRER can give me that info)

I'm running LAMP on a VPS with cPanel installed.  I can edit the DNS Zone file for the domain via WHM.

Comment: Don't redirect for an error.  Just have it issue the error directly (display the 404 error directly instead of redirecting)...  Otherwise you'll break the standard by issuing a 30x error for a location that doesn't exist, and then a 404 error for a location that does exist...

Comment: As @ircmaxell sais, with the addition that you could opt for (1) configuring a `*.example.com` vhost for non-existant subdomains (provided you have them all explicitly defined in another vhost) and (2) With the proper log settings, Apache can log the requested http-host & referer for you, and for parsing those logs to get statistics a multitude of tools are available.

Comment: @ircmaxell Redirect might have been the wrong word.  I would like to show a 404 page regardless, regardless of the physical location of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours ticketing my server's support center, I finally got wildcard subdomains set up.

Now when a user goes to subdomain.example.com, if that subdomain was explicitly set up via cPanel, it will function appropriately.  If that subdomain was not explicitly set up then it will be interally redirected to example.com, where I can grab the subdomain that they used and handle it as necessary (show a page, redirect to a subdomain, or show a 404 error).

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of tutorials on how to create a custom 404 page, no need to redirect as apache should take care of this for you.

- http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/create_custom_404_pages/
- http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/custom404.shtml
- http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/custom404error.html

Comment: These links are for setting up a 404 page on a domain that exists.  In my scenario, a user might go to sub.example.com where the subdomain "sub" has not been created and does not exist.  Currently when a browser hits a non-existent subdomain, it simply tells you that it can't resolve the server.  I want to go to an error page instead.