# How can I redirect non-existing sub-domains to domain [using .htaccess]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Suppose, a user (of a website), types a random, not-existing sub-domain name:

```
random.example.com
```

Is it possible to redirct them to the [main] domain:

```
example.com
```

The issue is that, if users type [or misspell] a sub-domain name - then currently, it goes to a [404] error page. Yet, I have already placed:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com
```

In the .htaccess - but, it does not redirect. Is it possible to create some kind of rewrite conditions/rules for a wildcard, such as all sub-domains that do not exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858385/creating-an-error-page-for-a-subdomain-that-doesnt-exist#comment4112527_3863966

Comment: "currently, it goes to a [404] error page" - So, you do actually get a 404 error (ie. the domain resolves - you must have a "wildcard" subdomain) and not an unresolved error as stated in the linked comment? If the former then you should be able to set an `ErrorDocument` (wherever it is pointing to), however, if it does not "resolve" then you will not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the sub-domains's vhost's document root are pointing to somewhere else, so probably you cannot do this.

On the other hand in the main apache config, you could use the ServerAlias directive to catch more domains with regular expressions or if you can control the default virtual host (the first usually), you can use rewrite rules as well.